# Flutter Web not displaying NetworkImages from Firebase storage, works perfectly on android emulator however

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

As in the title, I am deploying my app to Flutter Web and I am displaying pictures from Firebase storage. When testing on the android emulator, it works perfectly and displays all images without error. However, when I deploy it to my web app, images don't show at all for some reason. Below I added the relevant code snippet which shows how I display the pictures from Firebase (which, again, works perfectly fine on Android emulator) and the error on the web app when it tries to display the pictures.

**Code:**

```
void checkImages() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("uploads")
        .where('username', isEqualTo: Constants.myName)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("uploads")
            .doc(result.id)
            .collection("images")
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) async {
            imageCount++;
            final ref =
                FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(result.data()['imageid']);
            url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
            setState(() {
              printImages();
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }

  printImages() {
    return List.generate(imageCount, (index) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print( "hello");
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          child: Image.network(
            url.toString(),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

**Error in web console:**

```
main.dart.js?version=19:3082 Uncaught MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method StorageReference#getDownloadUrl on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage)
    at Object.a (https://social-io-102b4.firebaseapp.com/main.dart.js?version=19:3082:3)
    at https://social-io-102b4.firebaseapp.com/main.dart.js?version=19:53813:15
    at adv.a (https://social-io-102b4.firebaseapp.com/main.dart.js?version=19:4517:71)
    at adv.$2 (https://social-io-102b4.firebaseapp.com/main.dart.js?version=19:30063:23)
    at acI.$1 (https://social-io-102b4.firebaseapp.com/main.dart.js?version=19:30055:30)
    at No.mY (https://social-io-102b4.firebaseapp.com/main.dart.js?version=19:31072:40)
    at a82.$0 (https://social-io-102b4.firebaseapp.com/main.dart.js?version=19:30474:11)
    at Object.rs (https://social-io-102b4.firebaseapp.com/main.dart.js?version=19:4637:40)
    at a1.nL (https://social-io-102b4.firebaseapp.com/main.dart.js?version=19:30390:3)
    at a7V.$0 (https://social-io-102b4.firebaseapp.com/main.dart.js?version=19:30432:22)
```

To add to this, I am pretty sure I have all plugins installed correctly, because it works on Android. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Even after releasing a stable version of flutter web there are still some issues to be fixed. Even I am facing missing plugin implementation Issues. If you have installed all the packages correctly then most probably its web support is not proper yet. You should look for this issue on github where the developers are involved.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try adding this **script tag** to your index.html, after you have initialized it with the Firebase credentials (you get them when you add a new web-app in Firebase)

```
//import the Firestore plugin
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.10/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Take a look at this website to see all the plugins you may want to import:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#expandable-8

Comment: Thanks! So I did already have this plugin installed, but it was an old version; after seeing the link you posted with version 8.2.10, I realised that my version was outdated. Also, another thing that stopped images from loading was that I needed CORS permission.